# How to write this code without repetition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

What would be an easier and cleaner way to write this code below in Python? I know there has to be a simpler way to write multiple Or statements in Python but can't figure out one that suits my example.

```
def liquid_add_to_cart(liquid):
    actions.sleep_for_secs(1.5)
    
    if liquid.__contains__("Water"):
        add_water_btn_x, add_water_btn_y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('pictures/shopping/add_to_cart_btn.png',
                                                                          confidence=.8)
        pyautogui.click(add_water_btn_x, add_water_btn_y)
        pyautogui.click(button='left', clicks=water_cap, interval=2.0)
    
     elif liquid.__contains__("Juice"):
        add_juice_btn_x, add_juice_btn_y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('pictures/shopping/add_to_cart_btn.png',
                                                                          confidence=.8)
        pyautogui.click(add_juice_btn_x, add_juice_btn_y)
        pyautogui.click(button='left', clicks=juice_cap, interval=2.0)
    

      elif liquid.__contains__("Milk"):
        add_milk_btn_x, add_milk_btn_y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('pictures/shopping/add_to_cart_btn.png',
                                                                        confidence=.8)
        pyautogui.click(add_milk_btn_x, add_milk_btn_y)
        pyautogui.click(button='left', clicks=milk_cap, interval=2.0)
```

Comment: You can use dictionaries

Comment: Methods such as `__contains__` are generally not meant to be called directly.

Comment: btw, stop doing `liquid.__contains__("Water")`, you should do `"Water" in liquid`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the centre coordinates you are using in the if elif statements go out of scope after the execution of the statements.

If not, just add them as function parameters in the code below:

```py
path = 'pictures/shopping/add_to_cart_btn.png'

def liq(liq_cap):
    add_liq_btn_x, add_liq_btn_y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(path, confidence=.8)
    pyautogui.click(add_liq_btn_x, add_liq_btn_y)
    pyautogui.click(button='left', clicks=liq_cap, interval=2.0)

def liquid_add_to_cart(liquid):
    actions.sleep_for_secs(1.5)
    
    if liquid.__contains__("Water"):
        liq(water_cap)
    
    elif liquid.__contains__("Juice"):
        liq(juice_cap)
    
    elif liquid.__contains__("Milk"):
        liq(milk_cap)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
liqdict = {
    "Water": [add_water_btn_x, add_water_btn_y, water_cap],
    "Juice": [add_juice_btn_x, add_juice_btn_y, juice_cap],
    "Milk": [add_milk_btn_x, add_milk_btn_y, milk_cap]
}

def liquid_add_to_cart(liquid, liqdict):
    actions.sleep_for_secs(1.5)

    for key in liqdict.keys:
        if liquid.__contains__(key):
            btn_x = liqdict[key][0]
            btn_y = liqdict[key][1]
            cap = liqdict[key][2]
            btn_x, btn_y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(
                'pictures/shopping/add_to_cart_btn.png',
                confidence=.8)
            pyautogui.click(btn_x, btn_y)
            pyautogui.click(button='left', clicks=cap, interval=2.0)
                 break
```

You have't revealed how these globals are defined, so this might not work right out of the box; but hopefully this should get you moving in the right direction. Perhaps more generally you should arrange your data structures into a dictionary rather than a long list of global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need a control structure. In this case a list of tuples should suffice.

```
import pyautogui

water_cap = 2
juice_cap = 3
milk_cap = 4

CONTROL = [('Water', water_cap), ('Juice', juice_cap), ('Milk', milk_cap)]
PNG = 'pictures/shopping/add_to_cart_btn.png'

def liquid_add_to_cart(liquid):
    for k, v in CONTROL:
        if k in liquid:
            break
    else:
        v = 1
    btn_x, btn_y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(PNG, confidence=0.8)
    pyautogui.click(btn_x, btn_y)
    pyautogui.click(button='left', clicks=v, interval=2.0)
```

Assumption that water_cap, juice_cap and milk_cap (whatever they are?) are in scope.

What this means is that the function code doesn't need to change. All you need to do is add appropriate values to the CONTROL list

Comment: Ok I like this however how would I go about creating an else statement with this loop?  For context I am feeding in a list of groceries and I need to check if any of the groceries passed in contain the words water, liquid, juice, etc. If they dont then I need my code to just iterate through the list and move on. I have tried writing an else clause but that doesnt work the way I want it to. So would you have any possible ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: @KyleG. No additional code is needed. If the parameter passed(*liquid*) doesn't contain any of the key values in the CONTROL list then they will just be ignored

Comment: But I need “v” to be 1 if nothing is found in CONTROL. Wouldn’t there need to be an else clause otherwise v will throw back a 0

Comment: @KyleG. *v* cannot be 1 because it's used as a reference to a function. Perhaps you should give an example of what *liquid* might look like

Comment: Liquid will be a series of strings for example "H-E-B Texas Sized Hamburger Buns", “Lactaid Milk”, “Roast beef” , etc. If liquid contains the words "Milk", "Juice", "Cereal", "Water", etc. in the string then I need “v” to be the value of its key-value pair. If not then it should be 1.  I need to do this all while iterating through the rest of the items being passed through “liquid”

Is there any way to achieve this in one method? I feel like it’s not possible but I could be mistaken

Comment: Are you saying that *water_cap* (for example) is an integer? If so, it would have helped a lot if you had shown more complete code in your question

Comment: @KyleG. See edited answer. Perhaps this is what you're looking for. Note the *for/else* construct